# online alignment editor/widget

Tags: align, editors, alignat

Various editors provide matrix functionality, such as [TeXShop](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/index.html) or [this one I just found](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).  The ideal version doesn't require any arrow keys at all, like in TeXShop - you just have an Excel-like array and enter things, then click the button to put it in your document.

To my knowledge, there isn't something similar for aligned environments.  TeXShop will give you something like this

```
\begin{align}
\label{}
    &   \\
    &  
\end{align}
```

but it's not really a GUI in the same sense as its matrix editor.

> Is there an online (or not) aligned equation editor that allows you to just type in the formulas and then provides the alignment ampersands automatically in a GUI format?

I hope this question is clear enough.

Comment: Nothing personal, but what I like best about LaTeX is the total absence of a GUI format.  To me, mouse clicks are far less efficient than typing.

Comment: See https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ (but I agree with @StevenB.Segletes: much quickest typing than clicking)

Comment: I agree with both of you on principle; however, when it comes to reformatting existing text in a GUI, it leaves a lot to be desired.  This question is on behalf of a colleague who has a lot of equations to align, but is finding this aspect very tedious indeed.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - does this also do equation alignment?  It looks like it's just tables, but maybe I missed an option.

Comment: @kcrisman I don't know, I know it exists but I've never used it